# Index of Coincidence

Tags: python, for-loop, typeerror, attributeerror

I'm getting a TypeError. Its a cryptographic function. Index of Coincidence. I found one very similar that I began changing mine to match more. The only thing I've come to differently is the for statement line. Here is a link to that function. http://jdege.us/crypto-python/ar01s08.html#id2963591

It is not the original link, but it looks like a copy from someone else. "self.count.values():" returns an AttributeError

```
def ioc(self):
  numerator = 0.0
  denomenator = 0.0
  for val in self.count(self):
    i = val
    numerator += i * (i - 1)
    denomenator += i
  if (denomenator == 0.0):
    return 0.0
  else:
    return numerator / ( denomenator * (denomenator - 1))

usr = str(input("Insert text here:"))

ioc(usr)
```

Comment: If not done already you should work through the [Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/)

Comment: I don't have time for that. I know basics of Python, but I don't know why this isn't working. Thank you though.

Answer (score 0):

You can't iterate over an int, you have to use range(int):

```
def ioc(self):
    numerator = 0.0
    denominator = 0.0
    for val in range(self.count(self)):
        i = val
        numerator += i * (i - 1)
        denominator += i
    if (denominator == 0.0):
        return 0.0
    else:
        return numerator / ( denominator * (denominator - 1))

usr = str(input("Insert text here:"))

ioc(usr)
```